# Getting Started with Angular Gantt not loading 'gantt' module

Tags: angularjs

When I tried to load gantt in the module I get an $injector:moduleer error meaning it has trouble loading. I am also using Laravel.

In my script.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['gantt']); //error here
myApp.controller("appController", function($scope) {

$scope.data = [
        {
            name: 'row1',
            tasks : [
                {name: 'task1', from: 1470854811, to:  1470941211 },
                {name: 'task2', from: 1470854811, to:  1470941211 }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'row2', 
            tasks: [
                {name: 'task3', from: 1470854811, to:  1470941211},
                {name: 'task4', from: 1470854811, to:  1470941211}
              ]
        }
    ];
});
```

Lavarel gulpfile.js, i have already comfirm what i expect it to be loaded is being loaded

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('resources/assets/bower/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt.css', 'public/css/angular-gantt.css');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/bower/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-plugins.css', 'public/css/angular-gantt-plugins.css');
    mix.sass('style.scss');


    //defaults to resources/assets/js
    mix.scripts([
        '../bower/angular/angular.min.js',
        '../bower/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt.js',
        '../bower/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-plugins.js',
        '*.js' //this will load my script.js
    ]);

});
```

index.php in my resources/view

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController" >
    <div gantt data=data>

    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to get my hello world

Answer (score 1):

You may need to import "angular-momentjs": "^0.2.2" into the project. To build the gantt chart with given date range momentjs library is used to manipulate the date ranges.

https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Angular-momentjs is an implication of momentjs library for angular projects.